# How exactly works this implementation of the query() method of the Spring JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a Spring application that use `JdbcTemplate` to query the database and I have some doubts about how exactly it works.

So, into a service class, I have this method definition that performs a query:

```
//JDBC TEMPLATE SELECT EXAMPLE 
public List<DBLog> queryAllLogs() {
    System.out.println("JDBCExample: queryAllLogs() is called");    

    final String QUERY_SQL = "SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER BY IDLOG";

    List<DBLog> dbLogList = this.jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY_SQL, new RowMapper<DBLog>() {

        public DBLog mapRow(ResultSet resulSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            System.out.println("Getting log: "+ rowNum + " content: " + resulSet.getString("LOGSTRING"));

            DBLog dbLog = new DBLog();
            dbLog.setIDLOG(resulSet.getInt("IDLOG"));
            dbLog.setLOGSTRING(resulSet.getString("LOGSTRING"));
            return dbLog;
        }
    });
    return dbLogList; 
}
```

This method simply perform a query that return all the records inside a `LOG` table orderd by the `IDLOG` field value. This is pretty simple to understand.

Reading on the official documentation I found that this implementation of the `query()` method take 2 objects: the query string and a `RowMapper` object and that:

> Query using a prepared statement, mapping each row to a Java object
>   via a RowMapper

So I think that the `QUERY_SQL` query String is automatically converted into a `PreparedStatment` by the `query()` method implementation (is it right or am I missing something?)

The thing that is absolutly not clear for me is that it seems to me that in the previous example, I am defining a `RowMapper` implementation as second parameter of the query method.

So this specific implemention contain the `mapRow(ResultSet resulSet, int rowNum)` method implementation that from what I have understand is called for each row of the `ResultSet` object returned by the query execution. So this method will automatically map a specific row on a `DBLog` that will be automatically added to the returned `List<DBLog> dbLogList` list.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Who do all this work? Is it this specific `query()` method implementation (the one that take these 2 specific input parameter) that take care to call the `mapRow()` method of the passed `RowMapper` object and then add the returned `DBLog` object to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is entirely correct.

First, take a look at [this table in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-introduction). It lists everything that Spring JDBC automatically does and what you are left to do. Basically, all you need to do when using Spring JDBC is:

- setting up the JDBC connection
- specify the SQL statement to execute
- provide parameters value if there are parameters
- for each result, do the work of converting the result to an object

[`JDBCTemplate.query(String, RowMapper)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) follows the same pattern. First, you give it a SQL statement to execute: this is the first parameter (point 2 of the list above). Second, you give it an object which will be responsible for translating each result into your domain object (point 4 of the list above).

This object is called a `RowMapper` because it *maps* rows of a database, represented by a `ResultSet` object, into your domain object.

This is one of the main advantage of using Spring JDBC over raw JDBC: it factors out all the common and repeating tasks into its core. Yes, it will use a `PreparedStatement` under the hood, that is going to be executed and the `ResultSet` will be looped over. And in each iteration of this loop (made by Spring JDBC), your `RowMapper` will be called. Its result will be aggregated into a `List` by Spring JDBC and finally returned.

Comment: Ok, tnx now it is clear. Only a doubt: can I use Spring JdbcTemplate to operate directly with the ResultSet in some way?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Operate how? There's a [query](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-) method that gives you the complete ResultSet for you to loop over with a `ResultSetExtractor` but I'm not sure that what you meant.

Comment: I exactly mean what you have specified, tnx again :-)